# Wildcard redirect links going to root to subfolder on same domain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have moved a website from [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) to [www.example.com/subfolder](http://www.example.com/subfolder) and using an .htaccess file, I would like to redirect old links going to www.example.com to www.example.com/subfolder. My current .htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/$1 [L]
```

I've also tried the following:

```
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder/
#RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.example.com/subfolder%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,L]
```

I keep getting redirect loops or the redirect not working and leading to an error 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule in site root .htaccess (parent directory of `subfolder`) as the **first rule**:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(?!subfolder/)(.*)$ /subfolder/$1 [L,NC,NE,R=301]

# remaining rules go here
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache completely when testing this change.

Comment: Hi, i'm getting an internal server error with this. I've cleared browser completely.

Comment: Sorry I had a typo. It is fixed now. Can you try again

Comment: Thanks. The rules work. I have a website in the root and links to the existing files in the root are now all going to /subfolder. Is there a way to first check is a link exists in root first then redirect to /subfolder if it doesn't since it will be a link to the old website?

Comment: The updated rule works & doesn't work at the same time. I added test.html to /subfolder and went to example.com/test.html which redirected to example.com/subfolder/test.html. This works. I then added test-redone.html to the root (example.com) and went to example.com/test-redone.html but it redirected to example.com/subfolder/test-redone.html and gives a 404 page not found and a ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

Comment: Does test-redone.html also exist in subfolder? Did you try clearing your browser cache?

Comment: test-redone.html doesn't exist in /subfolder. I also cleared cache and used incognito window as well.

Comment: That is strange because exact same rules work on my Apache and shows 200 status for `localhost/test-redone.html`

Comment: This works. It was an issue with my cache. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

are you using wordpress? Or you just moving in general?

If you are moving in general this one-liner will work

```
RedirectMatch ^/$ /subfolder/
```

Original answer from [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/9992/how-to-get-apache2-to-redirect-to-a-subdirectory)

This is another solution i'm using currently.

**Do not copy and paste**. You need to **Replace DOMAIN** (without the .com) and **SUBFOLDER** to the name u want.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.

# Rewrite all those to insert /folder
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I'm not using Wordpress. I've just moved the website to a subfolder and added a new website to the root. I want the old links from old site to link to the subfolder for SEO.

Comment: I've tried this solution but i get an error 404 when i try an old link. I tried www.example.com/test.html but it didn't redirect to www.example.com/subfolder/test.html

Comment: can u try the new rule i added.